# (Error 10054 socket.error) Connection reset, by the tracker, upon issuing announce request

Tags: python, sockets, bittorrent

I am trying to develop a simple bittorrent client in Python for my own learning purpose. I am able to get the connection request/response working correctly. But as soon as I issue announce request I get the "socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error. I have tried my code on multiple udp trackers but I get the same issue with all of them.

For you reference my code: https://gist.github.com/zhaphod/9870825

Code is fairly small at 137 lines and the issue occurs at line 112.

I would appreciate any hints/solutions to the issue.

Comment: First guess - fix your malformed announce request.

Comment: I haven't sent tracker request over UDP. Why are you using server port 80 to send UDP request?